# Using handler function to send a signal to a child process

Tags: c, unix

The parent process has to send a SIGKILL signal to a child process after an alarm. I must do this changing the handler function of SIGALARM, however I do not know how to pass the child process as an argument to the handler function.

```
void mi_handler(int num)
{
    kill(getpid(),SIGKILL);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
   

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {   
        alarm(5);
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);   
    }

    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = mi_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&act,NULL);

  return(0);
}
```

This was my first solution but it doesn't do exactly what it is asked. I want to do something like this:

```
void mi_handler(int num)
{
    
    kill(child_process,SIGKILL);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
   

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {   
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);   
    }

    alarm(5);
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = mi_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&act,NULL);

  return(0);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assign `pid` to the global variable `child_process`.

```
pid_t child_process;

void mi_handler(int num)
{
    
    kill(child_process,SIGKILL);
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
   

    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {   
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);   
    }

    child_process = pid;
    alarm(5);
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = mi_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&act,NULL);

    // wait for alarm before exiting
    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);                                                             
    sigaddset(&set, SIGALRM);
    sigwait(&set);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Need a waitpid in there. (Yeah, I know it was missing in the OP too)

Comment: Good point. I added sigwait instead.